# How to access application setting through markup using expression?

Tags: asp.net

In a repeater control I've Eval binding as:

```
<%#Eval("PubDate", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>
```

But date time format needs to be configurable from the web.config. 
I want to access datetime format from web.config in markup like:

```
<%#Eval("PubDate", "{0:<%$ AppSettings: DateTimeFormat %>}")%>
```

But is is not working...
Any suggesions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property on your page in code behind (e.g. AppDateTimeFormat) which accesses DateTimeFormat from the AppSettings and use it like this:

```
    <%#Eval("PubDate", AppDateTimeFormat)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<%# Eval("PubDate", "{0:" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateTimeFormat"] + "}")%>
```

Edit: I'd recommend placing the parenthesis inside the String. Then you'd be able to use

```
<%# Eval("PubDate", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateTimeFormat"])%>
```